# Angular unit test problem with ngModel using ng-mocks

Tags: angular, ngmodel, ng-mocks

SOLVED. Code in the end.

I have a specific issue with using ng-mocks and testing ngModel.

The following is my unit test, with marked line which fails:

```
        it('should not move focus, and should delete current input value when backspace clicked inside filled input', fakeAsync(() => {
            const fixture = MockRender(SixDigitInputComponent);
            const inputs = ngMocks.findAll('input');
            const focusSpy = spyOn(inputs[0].nativeElement, 'focus');
            
            ngMocks.change(inputs[0], 3);
            ngMocks.change(inputs[1], 2);

            expect(inputs[0].nativeElement.value).toBe('3');
            expect(inputs[1].nativeElement.value).toBe('2');

            ngMocks.trigger(inputs[1], 'keydown.backspace');
            fixture.detectChanges();
            tick();
            expect(inputs[0].nativeElement.value).toBe('3'); // fails here "expects '' to be '3'"
            expect(inputs[1].nativeElement.value).toBe('');

            expect(focusSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));
```

All other expect lines work fine.

But when i replaced ngMocks.change with these lines, all passed:

```
            inputs[0].nativeElement.value = 3;
            inputs[0].nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
            inputs[1].nativeElement.value = 2;
            inputs[1].nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

some.component.html

```
<div class="code-input-container">
    <input
        #inputField
        (paste)="pasteValue($event)"
        (keydown.backspace)="clearFieldAndBacktrack(0)"
        (ngModelChange)="writeAndMoveToNext($event, 0)"
        [ngModel]="displayNumbers[0]"
        type="text"
        maxlength="1"
        placeholder="0"
    />
    <input
        #inputField
        (paste)="pasteValue($event)"
        (keydown.backspace)="clearFieldAndBacktrack(1)"
        (ngModelChange)="writeAndMoveToNext($event, 1)"
        [ngModel]="displayNumbers[1]"
        maxlength="1"
        type="text"
        placeholder="0"
    />
    <input
        #inputField
        (paste)="pasteValue($event)"
        (keydown.backspace)="clearFieldAndBacktrack(2)"
        (ngModelChange)="writeAndMoveToNext($event, 2)"
        [ngModel]="displayNumbers[2]"
        maxlength="1"
        type="text"
        placeholder="0"
    />
</div>
```

some.component.ts

```
    public writeAndMoveToNext(digit: string, i: number): void {
        if (!digit || !this.regex.test(digit)) {
            return;
        }
        this.displayNumbers[i] = Number(digit);
        this.focusOn(i + 1);
        this.onTouch();
        this.onChangeFn(this.displayNumbers.join(''));
    }

    public clearFieldAndBacktrack(i: number): void {
        if (i === -1) {
            return;
        }
        // on second backspace, clear and focus on previous input field
        if (this.displayNumbers[i] === null) {
            this.clearFieldAndBacktrack(i - 1);
            return;
        }
        this.focusOn(i);
        this.displayNumbers[i] = null;
        this.onTouch();
        this.onChangeFn(this.displayNumbers.join(''));
    }
```

Why this didnt trigger ngModel change in DOM:

```
            ngMocks.change(inputs[0], 3);
            ngMocks.change(inputs[1], 2);
```

And this did:

```
            inputs[0].nativeElement.value = 3;
            inputs[0].nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
            inputs[1].nativeElement.value = 2;
            inputs[1].nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Solution:

```
    it('should move focus to previous input and delete its value when backspace is clicked inside empty input', fakeAsync(() => {
            const fixture = MockRender(SixDigitInputComponent);
            const inputs = ngMocks.findAll('input');
            const focusSpy = spyOn(inputs[0].nativeElement, 'focus');

            ngMocks.change(inputs[0], '3');
            ngMocks.change(inputs[1], '2');
            fixture.detectChanges();

            expect(inputs[0].nativeElement.value).toBe('3');
            expect(inputs[1].nativeElement.value).toBe('2');

            ngMocks.trigger(inputs[1], 'keydown.backspace');
            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                expect(inputs[0].nativeElement.value).toBe(3);
                expect(inputs[1].nativeElement.value).toBe('');
                expect(focusSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
            });
    }));
```

Comment: Hi Tomas, could you share `beforeEach` how you configure `TestBed`? I would assume it misses a mock or kept `FormsModule`.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you keep `FormsModule` in your tests.

In this case, it's important to keep in mind that `NgModel` requires `await fixture.whenStable();`, and `fixture.detectChanges()` with `tick()` aren't enough.

remove `fakeAsync` and switch to `async/await`:

```
  it('should ...', async () => { // <-- make it async
    const fixture = MockRender(TargetComponent);
    await fixture.whenStable(); // <-- let ngModel render inputs correctly

    const inputs = ngMocks.findAll('input');
    const focusSpy = spyOn(inputs[0].nativeElement, 'focus');

    ngMocks.change(inputs[0], '3');
    ngMocks.change(inputs[1], '2');
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <-- let ngModel render inputs correctly
    await fixture.whenStable(); // <-- let ngModel render inputs correctly

    expect(inputs[0].nativeElement.value).toBe('3');
    expect(inputs[1].nativeElement.value).toBe('2');

    ngMocks.trigger(inputs[1], 'keydown.backspace');
    fixture.detectChanges(); // <-- let ngModel render inputs correctly
    await fixture.whenStable(); // <-- let ngModel render inputs correctly

    expect(inputs[0].nativeElement.value).toBe('3');
    expect(inputs[1].nativeElement.value).toBe('');

    expect(focusSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Now `nativeElements` should be in sync with `ngModel` and its value.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hardcore-butterfly-ks2r8l?file=%2Fsrc%2Ftest.spec.ts%3A98%2C1

Comment: Hi. I checked this unit test, and your solution helped me to find the one that worked, thanks! fixture.whenStable().then(...) worked. Regarding beforeEach, yes, FormsModule is kept. Tho in your solution async / await didnt work for me as it is deprecated. So am updating my original post with solution, that worked.